# Swiftui get top padding from system

Tags: swiftui

I am following some tutorial in which i need to get the top height.

I am doing right this now

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
        .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    
    // MARK: - body
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                NavigationBarView()
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .padding(.top, keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.top)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.05), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                
                Spacer()
                
                FooterView().padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .background(colorBackground.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
    }
}


// MARK: - Preview
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Issue is in preview it's working fine but on simulator it's not working.

[image]

Also, I have find this code then

```
extension UIApplication {
    var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets? {
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .filter {$0.activationState == .foregroundInactive }
            .map { $0 as? UIWindowScene }
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .first?.windows
            .filter {$0.isKeyWindow}
            .first
 
        return keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets
    }
}
```

and use it like `.padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.safeAreaInsets?.top)`

Then its working on simulator but not on preview. Just looking for solution which will work on both.

I try to remove .ignoreSafeArea but issue is I need padding on navbar and for responsive like on iPhone 8 i need little large padding on iPhone 13 I need to less so that's why I think need to get padding from safe area inspect

My code if I remove .ignoreSafeArea

```
    ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                NavigationBarView()
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.05), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                Spacer()

            }
            .background(colorBackground.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
        
    }
```

Its Preview
[image]

Comment: Why did you add .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top) to your code? Because of that you go through crazy efforts to compensate that by getting the key window and it's safe area insets. The code for getting the key window is not correct as it only run once rather than every time the key window changes. But I wouldn't fix that but rather get rid of .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top) then you don't need that code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Tamas comment, you don't need all of that. Just do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            NavigationBarView()
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
            
            Spacer()
            
            FooterView().padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but to get responsive height from top that’s why i am using that. If i try to use without that then in without notch iPhone i am getting very low padding.

Answer (score -1):

```
func topInsetHeight() -> CGFloat {
    
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else  {
        return 0
        
    }
    let topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top
    return topPadding
}
```

USAGE:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    ...

    // MARK: - body
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                NavigationBarView()
                    .ignoresSageArea() // Added this
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    .padding(.top, topInsetHeight()) // Change made here
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.05),
                            radius: 5,
                            x: 0,
                            y: 5
                     )
                Spacer()
                FooterView().padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .background(colorBackground)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}


// MARK: - Preview
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```